# Which rabbanim of the generation did the Baal Shem Tov meet with?

Tags: rabbis, baal-shem-tov

For example he met with the Nodah Beyehudah and the Shaagas Aryeh. Do we know if he met with the Yaavetz, Reb Yonasan Eybushitz, Pney Yehoshua?

Comment: He was the brother in law of Rabbi Gershon of Kitov.

Comment: I'd doubt: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Landau#Opposition_to_Chasiddus I can't recall an episode of the Yaavetz life either, when he travelled there.

Comment: Although: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Leib_ben_Asher_Gunzberg#Life